# Changing User of Application Pool

Tags: 2011-sp1

recently I have changed the Tridion Application Pool User to domain user.
When I try to grant on RSA KEY I obtain the next error:

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -PA "TridionRsaKey
Container" "domain\username"

Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.34209
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Adding ACL for access to the RSA Key container...
No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. (Exception from HRES
ULT: 0x80070534)
Failed!

Could any helps me please?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you running aspnet_regiis in a command prompt with "Run as administrator"?

Comment: yes. Also I tried with the same user who ran the tridion installer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open PowerShell ISE AS Administrator
- Paste in the command Below and execute

  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" "Yourdomain\UserName"

Answer (score 1):

Use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) to run the command as the SYSTEM user.

`PsExec -i -s cmd.exe` opens a command prompt as the SYSTEM user. Use this to run the aspnet_regiis command.

Comment: It worked like a charm!